# Tkinter get_mouse

Tags: python, tkinter, graphics

When my mouse is outside the canvas, I still get a circle located at the top left corner. And I can see printed -1 -1 in the terminal. Why?

```
mouse_x = canvas.get_mouse_x()
mouse_y = canvas.get_mouse_y()    
canvas.create_oval(mouse_x, mouse_y, mouse_x + SIZE, mouse_y + SIZE)     
print(mouse_x, mouse_y)
```

I know how to improve my code. It's just interesting to me why I still get something in  this case.

Comment: The canvas doesn't have a `get_mouse_x` or `get_mouse_y` method. Are those custom methods that you've written? If so, include them in your example.

Comment: Indeed! It was part of a package based on tkinter (we use it at the University) . By get_mouse_x() I mean event.x

Answer (score 2):

When the mouse is outside the canvas, `canvas.get_mouse_x()` and `canvas.get_mouse_y()` will return the value `-1`. This is because the canvas coordinates start at (0, 0) in the top left corner, and when the mouse is outside the canvas, there is no meaningful coordinate to return.

In your code, you are using the returned value of `-1` as the x and y coordinates for creating an oval using `canvas.create_oval()`. This will create an oval at the top left corner of the canvas, with a width and height of SIZE.

The `print(mouse_x, mouse_y)` statement will print `-1 -1` to the terminal, indicating that the mouse is currently outside the canvas.